# beginners tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is there not a need for one or more special tags for beginners questions?

To me it looks as some posters have no idea what an abstract algebra is and think that their problem has something to do with algebra and this was the first tag that came up.

But then I saw a question about something simple like how do I transform this problem into a simple formula with 1 variable 
and was mystified which tag should I use to replace the abstract algebra  one.
(I did settle on recreational mathematics, but that hardly covers the subject )

Comment: See related previous discussions: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8396/filtering-tags-questions-by-subject-and-level-of-difficulty http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570/can-we-please-delete-the-high-school-tag

Comment: and the tag you are looking for is [tag:algebra-precalculus], whose tag-wiki states: "... and other symbolic-manipulation topics".

Comment: thanks, was also thinking about another solution, just remove the requirement to add at least one tag to a question

Comment: That is a horrible solution. Tagging is what makes the raging ocean of questions manageable. And that too is not a sufficient method on its own.

Comment: relevant meta question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10625/addressing-the-common-misuse-of-the-abstract-algebra-tag

Comment: You have mentioned in your post that you had problems with finding correct tags for some question. If you have doubts about tags for specific question, you can always ask in the [tagging chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3740/tagging) or in the [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/).

Answer (score 6):

I fully agree with Willie Wong in that [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/algebra-precalculus/info) is the appropriate tag. Many US based students (think they) have taken a course in algebra in high school, and have problems tagging here. A couple years back the tag `algebra' was blacklisted and split into *algebra-precalculus* and *abstract-algebra* to make the distinction between high school/freshman algebra and higher algebra.

I also think that your suggested solutions are not good. However, I upvoted your question for reminding us all about this persisting problem. It might be a good idea to give more tips about tagging in [the relevant section of the Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/tagging). The current one looks like it is copy/pasted from SO. It might benefit the newcomers to have a few rules of thumb layed down there - together with an assembly of links to the common tag wikis. If the mods are too busy, and this is judged helpful, I might volunteer to make the above changes. Of course, some other people who 1) know the American high school better, 2) know the English language better, and 3) have even more time, would do an even better job, so I won't stand in their way :-)

Comment: There was a proposal for [tagging section in Help Center](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10244/proposal-for-a-new-help-center-section-tagging).

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Martin. I didn't have anything nearly as comprehensive in mind, as I think that sophomore's and up should know (and do know?) better. I do realize now that the list might still easily become too bloated to be useful.

Comment: Well, the proposal has score -4 and several users commented that it is too detailed.

Comment: I am almost sure that [algebra] was blacklisted sometime in the past year, and dare I say in 2013.

Comment: @Asaf: I can't put a date on the blacklisting. But there was a massive retagging effort in IIRC 2011, when the split to abstract and precalculus algebra was done.

Comment: January 12th, 2013. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6299/should-the-algebra-tag-be-blacklisted

Comment: IIRC the [algebra] tag had no questions already in [February 2013](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3081/8297) but it kept popping again and again, until it was finally blacklisted.